# Pinescript change plot display based on string options input

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to change which plots are displayed based on string options, but I'm getting the following error:

Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 8: Invalid argument 'display' in 'plot' call. Possible values: [display.none, display.all]

```
//@version=5
// doesn't work
indicator("My script")
x = input.string(title="x", defval="one", options=["one","two"])
plot(close, display= x == "one" ? display.all : display.none)

// works
indicator("My script")
x = "one"
plot(close, display= x == "one" ? display.all : display.none)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the color to `na` you will not see it but the plot will still have a value.

Instead, you can apply your condition to the `series` argument of the `plot()` function. In this case, when your condition is `false` plot will have `na`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

x = input.string(title="x", defval="one", options=["one","two"])

c = x == "one" ? na : color.blue
p = x == "one"

plot(open, color=c)  // Won't be visible but will still its value
plot(p ? close : na, color=color.white)  // Will be na when false
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of

[Is there a way to hide specific indicator values from the data window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418248/is-there-a-way-to-hide-specific-indicator-values-from-the-data-window)

Changing display dynamically is not possible, but you can set color to na.